# Where to logout - for real?

Tags: feature-request, support, personalization

Cannot find a logout-link/button.

Yes, asked before - answered before. Lots of time. Know that. Unfortunetaly no one of the answers do the job.

If I log off Google, I'm still logged in to stackoverflow. If I'm logged off stackoverflow I'm still seing my credentials, as I see them - not how "foreign" people should see them.

Reason?
I want to see my profile as other see it.

Suggestion:
There should be a "how people see you"-feature.

Comment: A different browser you never use?

Comment: @McNab, Yeah - you should make this as an answer, and I accept it. But it doesnt solve the "real" problem. It is the same with google, facebook and so on - you are never ever really logged out, unless you go offline.

Comment: @davidkonrad. I have indeed done so, a rare answer on meta :)

Comment: wait... you log out...?

Comment: Use an incognito/private-browsing window.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, why would I, when the site I am happy with should have the feature?

Comment: I'm just giving you a work-around. It might be nice to have the feature, but since SO is not a social site, I doubt that it will be seen as high-priority.

Comment: @blorgbarg, agree, but there can be many reasons fr controlling your "face" in the *stack*-stack.

Comment: Incognito mode works. If you insist on actually logging out, use the “log out” link in your user dropdown (hover over your username in the top bar). It can’t log you out of your Google Account, but that has no influence over how your Stack Exchange accounts are seen if you aren’t actually logged in on the site itself.

Comment: all the above demon(d)syrates how weak people have become'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always just fire up a browser you don't normally use and [see yourself as others see you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Louse).

Note that this would increment your profile views.

Comment: This seems to be the overall answer ..

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a separate browser. Use the incognito browsing function of your browser:

- If you are using Firefox, Internet Explorer press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- If you are using Chrome, Opera press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: You can take away Ctrl+shift-P. I am not joking - try Ctrl L, that will make your life a lot easier. I know all the shortcuts. But your answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: But it was nice finally to get an excuse to use the kbd-tag :) I guess

Comment: So, another browser "solves" your issue but a private session using a current one does not? I am shocked!